# Radius of convergence and domain of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Question is to calculate Radius and domain of convergence for :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\arctan\frac{1}{x})^{n^2}$$

What I have tried is :

Radius of convergence is $1$ I am sure about this.

Coming to interval of convergence :

In general this converges only if $|\arctan\frac{1}{x}|<1$

i.e., $-1<\arctan\frac{1}{x} <1$

i.e., $-\tan1<\frac{1}{x}<\tan 1$

i.e., $x<-\frac{1}{\tan 1 }$ and $x>\frac{1}{\tan 1 }$

So, Interval of convergence is $(-\infty,-\frac{1}{\tan 1 })\cup(\frac{1}{\tan 1 },\infty)$

But the answer which is given is  $(-\infty,-\tan 1)\cup(\tan 1,\infty)$

I could not realize where did i go wrong..

Please help me to clear this...

Comment: It seems like your computation for the domain of convergence is correct, but that would imply that the radius of convergence is not 1.

Comment: Oh. yes.. a valid point... But I was just looking for formulafor finding radius of convergence $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=1$ :O.. I am not sure where did i go wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$u_n=\left(\arctan\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n^2}$$
then since
$$\left|\arctan\frac{1}{x}\right|<1\iff \left|\frac{1}{x}\right|<\tan1\iff |x|>\frac{1}{\tan1}$$
so using the Cauchy test we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|u_n\right|^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\arctan\frac{1}{x}\right|^n<1\iff |x|>\frac{1}{\tan1}=a$$
hence the given series is convergent *(and here we  do not speak of radius of convergence since we have not a power series)* on the domain
$$(-\infty,-a)\cup(a,+\infty)$$

Comment: As i have written i was sure of the domain of convergence... I like "and here we do not speak of radius of convergence since we have not a power series"... I really do not know this may be i have neglected that this is not power series and all.... Thank you so much..... I learned a new thing!!

Comment: ${+ \large + \Large + {\Huge +}} \to 1$

Answer (score 2):

The official answer is wrong, your answer is right. Plugging in $x = 1$, we have $\arctan 1 = \frac{\pi}{4} < 1$, so the series converges for $x = 1$, and we have

$$\frac{1}{\tan 1} < 1 < \tan 1,$$

showing that the official answer cannot be correct.

Comment: Thank you sir.... But as mentioned by some user i the comments, my radius of convergence calculation is wrong... but,$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=1$ :O.. so.. I am not sure :O